# Why is my trigger not updating the field?

Tags: apex, trigger, update, dmlexception

I have a custom object and it's related history by activating the history tracking of its field. However, I don't really understand why it's not updating my custom object field? Can someone please enlighten me.

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a015g00000rLCFsAAO; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, TestObject1Trigger: execution of AfterUpdate

```java
trigger TestObject1Trigger on TestObject1__c (after insert, before insert, after update, before update) {       
    if(trigger.isAfter) {  
        if(trigger.isUpdate) {
            TestObject1Class.updCall(trigger.new);                
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@future(callout=true)
public static void testMet1(Set<Id> deActIds) {    
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, List<TestObject1__History>> childRecordsByParentId = new Map<Id, List<TestObject1__History>>();
                 
    for(Id parent :deActIds){
        parentIds.add(parent);
        childRecordsByParentId.put(parent, new List<TestObject1__History>()); 
    }
                  
    List<TestObject1__History> childs = [SELECT Id, Field, DataType, NewValue, OldValue, ParentId, CreatedDate FROM TestObject1__History];
    System.debug('hist size' + childs.size());
            
    // query
    for(TestObject1__History historyRec :[SELECT Id, Field, DataType, NewValue, OldValue, ParentId, CreatedDate FROM TestObject1__History WHERE ParentId IN :parentIds ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC]){
        childRecordsByParentId.get(historyRec.ParentId).add(historyRec);         
    }                   
            
    Map<Id, TestObject1__c> mpUpdate = new Map<Id, TestObject1__c>();
    for(TestObject1__c parent : [SELECT Id, dt__c FROM TestObject1__c WHERE Id IN: parentIds]){
        Date dtUpd;
                 
        if(childRecordsByParentId.size() > 0) {
            for(TestObject1__History historyRec :childRecordsByParentId.get(parent.Id)){ 
                if(historyRec.NewValue == 'Checking') {
                    dtUpd = historyRec.CreatedDate.date();   
                }                   
                    
                TestObject1__c tObj = new TestObject1__c(Id = parent.Id, dt__c = dtUpd);
                mpUpdate.put(parent.Id, tObj);
            }

            System.debug('dt: ' + dtUpd + ' tObj id: ' + parent);               
        }                    
    }          
            
    // there are values in this map according to debug, yet its not updating
    System.debug(mpUpdate);
    update mpUpdate.values();     
}    

public static void updCall(List<TestObject1__c> tObjList) { 
    Set<Id> tObjIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(TestObject1__c rec : tObjList) {
        tObjIds.add(rec.Id);
    }
    TestObject1Class.testMet1(tObjIds);
}
```

Comment: During after phase the record is already put in the database and is not updated from further changes unless you perform DML.

Answer (score 0):

In my edit, I added the error message back because I thought it provided important context. Looking through your code though, I don't see how this error could happen.

### The current approach, and how to improve it

Assuming that you've worked past that error, and that you're refreshing the page for your test record (doing the work async here means it is done in a separate "transaction" in Salesforce. The page refresh you get after pushing the "save" button only reflects changes made in the trigger's "transaction") the only thing I'm really seeing here is your innermost for loop

```java
for(TestObject1__History historyRec :childRecordsByParentId.get(parent.Id)){ 
    if(historyRec.NewValue == 'Checking') {
        dtUpd = historyRec.CreatedDate.date();   
    }                   
                    
    TestObject1__c tObj = new TestObject1__c(Id = parent.Id, dt__c = dtUpd);
    mpUpdate.put(parent.Id, tObj);
}
```

If your `NewValue` isn't `'Checking'`, then `dtUpd` could be null. It could also be a date from a completely different parent record. If you're going to continue with this approach then I'd change the structure a bit

```java
for(TestObject1__History historyRec :childRecordsByParentId.get(parent.Id)){
    // If you use a variable inside of a loop and nowhere else, then it's usually
    //   a good idea to declare that variable inside of the loop so you don't
    //   need to worry about data leaking over (from a previous iteration)
    //Date dtUpd;

    // I prefer to keep as much logic out of if/else as I can.
    // Instead using if/else to select one out of many things, or to stop
    //   a record from being processed further (as we're doing here)
    if(historyRec.NewValue != 'Checking') {
        continue;
    }                   
    
    // Thanks to that "continue", we only get to this part of the loop if
    //   the current record's NewValue is 'Checking'                
    TestObject1__c tObj = new TestObject1__c(
        Id = parent.Id, 
        // dtUpd becomes unnecessary, we can just use the CreatedDate directly
        dt__c = historyRec.CreatedDate.date()
    );
    mpUpdate.put(parent.Id, tObj);
}
```

### A better approach (most of the time)

The above *should* work (and again, you need to refresh the record page again to see the update made by async apex). In many scenarios that involve finding the sum, max, min, or average values of child records though, it's usually possible to reduce the amount of code that needs to be written by using `GROUP BY` or a parent-child subquery.

e.g.

```java
for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT ParentId, MAX(CreatedDate) latestCreatedDate FROM TestObject1__History WHERE ParentId IN :parentIds AND NewValue = 'Checking' GROUP BY ParentId]){
    // We'll only have one record per parent id, so you don't even need a map
    //   (you could still use a map, but a plain 'ol list would suffice)
    updateList.add(new TestObject1(
        Id = (Id)ar.get('ParentId'),
        dt__c = ((Datetime)ar.get('latestCreatedDate')).date()
    ));
}
```

```java
// The analogue to the above, using a parent-child subquery
// Using ORDER BY and LIMIT, we can easily select a single record to get a max or min
for(TestObject1 parent :[SELECT Id, (SELECT CreatedDate FROM Histories WHERE NewValue = 'Checking' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)]{
    if(parent.Histories.isEmpty()){
        continue;
    }

    parent.dt__c = parent.Histories[0].CreatedDate.date();
    updateList.add(parent);
}
```

### Testing history is hard, and limits what we can do

While I would normally prefer one of the two solutions above (using queries to do the heavy lifting instead of doing the work in Apex proper), it's a bit of a different story with history records. **Testing code that relies on history records is notoriously difficult.**

- History records aren't created for records created in unit tests (or rather, they seem to be created after the "transaction" that is created for an individual test method, so they are never available to the test method)
- We also can't set `NewValue` or `OldValue` if we try to create our
  own instances of History records for a test (in-memory, as we can't
  insert)
- `Test.loadData()` will silently ignore attempts to set
  new/old value

So to make this code testable, we need to avoid queries and have the ability to set NewValue/OldValue. Given the restrictions we have, we need to create a wrapper/proxy class to accomplish that.

```java
public class HistoryWrapper{
    public Id ParentId;
    public Datetime CreatedDate;
    public Object NewValue;

    public HistoryWrapper(SObject genericHistory){
        ParentId = (Id)genericHistory.get('ParentId');
        CreatedDate = (Datetime)genericHistory.get('CreatedDate');
        NewValue = genericHistory.get('NewValue');
    }
}
```

Taking a page from fflib (apex enterprise patterns), creating a *selector* class to centralize and standardize how you use history elsewhere is probably a good idea. This is also where we can set ourselves up to be able to inject "history" in unit tests.

```java
public class HistorySelector{
    public static List<HistoryWrapper> injectedHistory;

    public static List<HistoryWrapper> selectByParentId(List<Id> parentIdList){
        if(injectedHistory != null){
            return injectedHistory;
        }

        List<HistoryWrapper> results = new List<HistoryWrapper>();
        for(SObject historyRec :Database.query(
            String.format('SELECT Id, ParentId, OldValue, NewValue, FieldName, CreatedDate FROM {0}__History WHERE ParentId IN :parentIdList',
                new List<Object>{ parentIdList.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName()}
            )
        ){
            results.add(new HistoryWrapper(historyRec));
        }

        return results;
    }

    public static List<HistoryWrapper> selectMaxCreatedDateGroupedByParentIdWithNewValue(List<Id> parentIdList, String targetNewVal){
        if(injectedHistory != null){
            return injectedHistory;
        }

        List<HistoryWrapper> results = new List<HistoryWrapper>();
        for(SObject historyRec :Database.query(
            String.format('SELECT ParentId, MAX(CreatedDate) FROM {0}__History WHERE ParentId IN :parentIdList AND NewValue = {1} GROUP BY ParentId',
                new List<Object>{
                    parentIdList.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName(),
                    targetNewVal
                }
            )
        ){
            HistoryWrapper wrappedHistory = new HistoryWrapper();
            wrappedHistory.ParentId = (Id)historyRec.get('ParentId');
            wrappedHistory.CreatedDate = (Datetime)historyRec.get('expr0');

            results.add(wrappedHistory);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Yes, we still have queries against history objects here, but the point is that we can contain those queries in this single class. All other "client" code that uses history data goes through this class to get it, and we can create (and return) test "history" data in the unit tests for the "clients" of the selector class.

```java
@future(callout=true)
public static void testMet1(Set<Id> deActIds) {
    List<Id> parentIdList = new List<Id>(deActIds);
    List<TestObject1__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<TestObject1__c>();
    
    // The important point here is that we are not directly querying for
    //   history in this class.
    // This is what makes this class/method testable
    for(HistoryWrapper hist :HistorySelector.selectMaxCreatedDateGroupedByParentIdWithNewValue(parentIdList, 'Checking')){
        TestObject1__c parentRecord = new TestObject1__c(
            Id = hist.ParentId,
            dt__c = hist.CreatedDate.date()
        );

        recordsToUpdate.add(parentRecord);
    }

    update recordsToUpdate;
}
```

and a test for this might look like

```java
@isTest
private class testClass{
    @isTest
    private static getMaxDateAsync_updatesRecord(){
        TestObject1__c testRec = new TestObject1__c();
        insert testRec;

        
        HistoryWrapper history1 = new HistoryWrapper();
        history1.ParentId = testRec.Id;
        history1.CreatedDate = Datetime.now().addDays(2);

        List<HistoryWrapper> testHistoryList = new List<HistoryWrapper>{ history1 };

        HistorySelector.injectedHistory = testHistoryList;

        Test.startTest();
        TestObject1Class.testMet1(new Set<Id>{ testRec.Id });
        Test.stopTest();

        TestObject1__c result = [SELECT Id, dt__c FROM TestObject1__c WHERE Id = :testRec.Id];

        Assert.areEqual(history1.CreatedDate, result.dt__c, 'Parent record did not have the correct date set');
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that these are mostly *examples* and are untested. It's the general ideas here that are the most important (use SOQL to do the heavy lifting, create Apex class(es) to help work around Salesforce's limitations).

It's very possible that you'll need to make some adjustments to get all of this to compile. If you do run into issues, it's my hope that you'll make an honest attempt to understand the issue and work through it yourself (as opposed to immediately making another question to have people work out minor syntax issues).